# How can I achieve pixel-perfect positioning and spacing of textual elements across browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser, text-rendering, pixel-perfect

Right now, we are trying to achieve consistent formatting of `textarea` elements, across Safari/Chrome/Firefox/IE on Mac and Windows. I believe this may be a rabbit hole, since any combination thereof could produce formatting in a slightly different way -- maybe one combination adds a bit of padding to a div here differently than the others, another one breaks multi-line text there differently than the others, and so on.

Instead of using `textarea` (or `div`) elements, can we achieve pixel-perfect positioning using HTML5's `canvas`? Or using the Raphael JavaScript library? Or maybe some other JS library?

Mainly, by pixel-perfect, what I mean is any arbitrary text should get rendered in the exact same way (especially with respect to line breaks and padding) in any of the above-mentioned browsers.

(I'd prefer to avoid Flash-based solutions for the moment, unless that is the *only* solution...)

Comment: where canvas is available you could achieve "near-pixel-perfect positioning" - difference lies in the way the different borwsers/versions access/interpret fonts/styles... "really pixel-perfect" is AFAIK possible only via Flash or Silverlight based solutions...

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Yes, in this case, it does. Your pithy comment is ignorant and unwanted.

Comment: You gotta be kidding. Why would your case be different? Generations of Web Developers have struggled to achieve what you're asking for, and have failed. Canvas and SVG make no difference, because the "problem" is font-rendering. The only viable "solution" is using Flash or [images](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2349-PHP-Render-a-text-string-as-an-image.html) instead of text, which makes web development look ridiculous.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 As you put it, generations of Web Developers struggled to create interactive webpages. Then times changed.

Answer (score 3):

Send the text to the server, have the server render an image, display the image. Voilà.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted. This totally answers the question. Text will be rendered pixel-perfectly in every browser without the use of Flash.

Comment: Sadly, this still seems to be the working answer. "Sadly" because the round-trip load on the amount of images I want pixel-perfect is not small (and the text is dynamically generated, so can't be pre-rendered).

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted either. Apple did something like this a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is nearly impossible.

I would also say that there is no reason to have *pixel perfect* across all browsers because the overwhelming majority of visitors only view your site with one browser.  And those who do visit your site in more than one browser (say at work and at home) are unlikely to notice elements that are off a few pixels or have slightly different border colors.

What we should be concerned about is that the content looks good in each browser.

That said, here's a great list of `textarea` tricks: http://css-tricks.com/6841-textarea-tricks/

Comment: The web application front-ends a WYSIWYG PDF generator. If textual element breaks at different points in different browsers, the PDF output will be inconsistent. Thus my question.

Comment: Ah! You should add this to the question.  It is important context.

Comment: I have a reason to be pixel-perfect across browsers and computers -- I'm trying to align text in separate elements so that they appear to be the same (long explanation involving infinite tiling and text generation).

Answer (score 1):

One main reason that PDF exists is that browsers are not about pixel-identical layout but PDF is.  Among other things, not even typefaces are guaranteed to be the same from one OS/browser to the next.

Even, if you don't let the browser position anything and you do all your own pixel level positioning, you still won't necessarily have the same fonts to work with.  If you let the browser position anything, then you can have variations.

Answer (score 0):

Would one solution be to begin your css with a clean slate?  Give everything a known default?

For example, I start my css files like this so I always know what to expect:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?  Similarly, you could change '*' to 'textarea'.

Comment: Yes, this definitely helps, but it doesn't handle issues with anonymous divs that CSS can never style, e.g. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=326123

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this question now: Consider using something like normalize.css instead of CSS resets: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible, however one thing you may want to look into is using the web developer toolbar for firefox or the web developer add-on for chrome. There is an option to disable browser default styles. Check this and then style **everything**. The borders, border type, all margins, paddings, background colors, etc. Then reenable browser default styles and make sure it looks the same. If not, wash, rinse and repeat.

Also, if fonts play a part, you will have to embed them into the page since some operating systems may not have a particular font installed.